# Ошибки при завершении программы. Прога для работы с бинарными файлами

Tags: c++, файлы

Написал прогу для заполнения/вывода бинарных файлов. Использую массив структур. Постоянно вылетают ошибки. Вторая вылетает, если пропустить первую. Не могу понять как это исправить
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include "for_lab.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
SetConsoleCP(1251); 
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
int n;
cout << "Сколько книг вы хотите внести в базу?\n";
cin >> n;
create_file(n);
cout << "________________________\nСодержимое файла:\n";
out_file(n);
cout << "AAAA\n";
return 0;
}

#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
struct book
{
long isbn;
char author[30], name[30];
int date;
};
void create_file(int n)
{
ofstream ff("file1.txt", ios::trunc | ios::out | ios::binary);
book *x = new book[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cout << "Введите данные книги " << i + 1 << "\nКод ISBN - "; cin >> 
x[i].isbn;
    cin.get();
    cout << "Название книги - "; cin.getline(x[i].name, 25);
    cout << "Автор - "; cin.getline(x[i].author, 25);
    cout << "Год издания - "; cin >> x[i].date;
    ff.write((char *)&x[i], sizeof(book));
}
n++;
x[n].isbn = 0;  strcpy(x[n].name, " ");
strcpy(x[n].author, " ");   x[n].date = 0;
ff.write((char *)&x[n], sizeof(book));
ff.close();
}
void out_file(int n)
{
ifstream ff("file1.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);
book x;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    ff.read((char*)&x, sizeof(book));
    cout << "Код ISBN - " << x.isbn << endl << x.name << "\nАвтор - " << 
x.author << "\nГод издания - " << x.date << endl;
}
ff.close();
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала вы выделили массив `n` книг `book *x = new book[n];`, а после цикла увеличиваете `n` на единицу и получаете переполнение буфера:

```
n++;
x[n].isbn = 0;  strcpy(x[n].name, " ");
```

Следует выделить `n+1` элементов и не изменять потом значение `n`.